# Pop up date (Method SelectDate is never used) in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pop up a edit text to choose the date and then store in that edit text. Im using this code. but SelectDate method is in grey and say: 'Method SelectDate is never used'.
My code:

```
package com.kargavibe.testes;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    EditText mEdit;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void selectDate(View view) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
    }
    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mEdit);
        mEdit.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
    }
    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
        }
    }
```

and my xml:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/mEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="+ Add Date"
        android:onClick="selectDate" />
```

When I play the app the edit text apears but when I click only show me the keyboard. Any advice?

Comment: Why do you use EditText? I think you should use TextView.

Comment: Because need to be editable and changable date

Comment: need to be editable with keyboard? Then, why are you show dialog?

Comment: I need to enter a date, then If i make a mistake I need to change date again. No, don't need to be editable with keyboard.